# Mahapps dialog boxes in mvvm light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to implement MahApps Messages in a WPF - MVVM Light application.

MahApps version: 1.3.0.0

I've found a [tutorial](https://dragablz.net/2015/05/29/using-mahapps-dialog-boxes-in-a-mvvm-setup/) showing how to do this, however I'm stuck in the first step:

I've already added the two lines mentioned in the tutorial:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="AppName.MainWindow"

   **xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
   Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"**  

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="Inicio de sesión" Height="280" Width="500"
    xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
```

But in the second line I'm getting the following error message:

```
The attachable property 'Register' was not found in type 'DialogParticipation'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: By "Added the following lines" do you mean you added that entire `Controls:MetroWindow` element to an existing window, or you just add the *attributes* to the element that already existed?  Showing some more of the XAML might help clarify this.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I've edited the question. Thanks for the comments.